# Find intervals which have a non-empty intersection with a given interval

Tags: python, sorting

The problem is the following: I have a list `intervals` which consists of tuples of the form `(start, end`) [with `start <= end`]. Each tuple represents an interval (of the real line). We assume that the intervals in `intervals` are not overlapping each other. Given a new interval `(s,e)`, I would like to write a Python function which checks if `(s, e)` overlaps any of the intervals in `intervals`. If `(s, e)` has a non-empty intersection with at least one of the intervals in `intervals`, the function should return the indices of these intervals in the list `intervals`.

Say that the function is called `find_intersections`. Then, given that `intervals = [(1, 3.5), (5.5, 8.7), (10.2, 22.6), (22.7, 23.1)]`, expected outputs would be:

- `find_intersection(intervals, (3.2, 5.))` returns `array([0])`
- `find_intersection(intervals, (6.1, 7.3))` returns `array([1])`
- `find_intersection(intervals, (9.1, 10.2))` returns `No intersection.`
- `find_intersection(intervals, (5.8, 22.9))` returns `array([1, 2, 3])`.

The code for `find_intersection` I have written is:

```
import itertools

def find_intersection(intervals, new_interval):
    _times = sorted(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(intervals)))
    ind = np.searchsorted(_times, np.asarray(new_interval))
    parity = np.mod(ind, 2)
    if (not np.any(parity)) and ind[1] == ind[0]:
        print('No intersection.')
    elif parity[0] == 1:
        ub = ind[1] if parity[1] == 1 else ind[1] - 1
        return np.arange((ind[0] - 1) / 2, (ub - 1) / 2 + 1)
    elif parity[1] == 1:
        lb = ind[0] if parity[0] == 1 else ind[0] + 1
        return np.arange((lb - 1) / 2, (ind[1] - 1) / 2 + 1)
    else:
        lb = ind[0] if parity[0] == 1 else ind[0] + 1
        ub = ind[1] if parity[1] == 1 else ind[1] - 1
        return np.arange((lb - 1) / 2, (ub - 1) / 2 + 1)
```

I believe that the code does the job.

**Is there an easier/smarter way to address this problem?**

Comment: Cross-posted and answered on Code Review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/203468/31562

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `i`-th interval in the list overlaps iff

```
start[i] < e and s < end[i].
```

So, sort the intervals by increasing `start` values, then scan the list until you find the first `end[i] > s` and continue as long as `start[i] < e`. Keep the indexes as you go.

This takes O(N Log N) for the sort, followed by Θ(N) worst-case for the search.

---

If sorting is allowed and you have many `(s,e)` intervals to try, it may be useful to find the first and the last `i` by dichotomic search among the `start[i]`and `end[i]` values rather than by linear search. This reduces the cost from Θ(M + K) to Θ(Log N), where M is the average index of the first overlap (normally M = O(N)) and K is the average number of overlaps.

---

If sorting is not allowed, you need to test every interval in turn for overlap, using the above condition. Cost Θ(N).

Answer (score 3):

```
intervals = [(1, 3.5), (5.5, 8.7), (10.2, 22.6), (22.7, 23.1)]


def find_intersection(intervals, new_interval):
    start, end = new_interval

    return (i for i, (a, b) in enumerate(intervals)
        if (a < start < b) or (a < end < b) or (a > start and b < end))


candidates = ((3.2, 5.), (6.1, 7.3), (9.1, 10.2), (5.8, 22.9))
for c in candidates:
    print(c, "->", list(find_intersection(intervals, c)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Two intervals intersect if

```
def intersect(i1, i2):
    return max(i1[0], i2[0]) < min(i1[1], i2[1])
```

So, just a list comprehension

```
def find intersection(intervals, i2):
    return [i1 for i1 in intervals if intersect(i1, i2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the [interval tree package](https://pypi.org/project/intervaltree/), which offers built-in functions that return a multitude of similar queries. Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a function that returns the indexes of the overlapping intervals, but only the intervals themselves. For example:

```
import IntervalTree

intervals = [(1, 3.5), (5.5, 8.7), (10.2, 22.6), (22.7, 23.1)]
tree = IntervalTree.from_tuples(intervals)

tree.search(3.2, 5.) % ~~>   {Interval(1, 3.5)}
tree.search(9.1, 10.2) % ~~> set()
tree.search(5.8, 22.9) % ~~> {Interval(5.5, 8.7), Interval(10.2, 22.6), Interval(22.7, 23.1)}
tree[5.8:22.9] % ~~>         same as above
```

Once you have the set of intervals you need, you can easily return their indexes:

```
[intervals.index((tr.begin, tr.end)) for tr in tree[5.8:22.9]]
```

If the list of intervals is large, you may want to make a dictionary instead and look up the indexes, because the `.index` method takes linear time wrt the list's length.

Although installing a package to tackle just this problem is probably an overhead, if you are dealing with intervals then using the [interval tree data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) and taking advantage of the underlying optimized methods written in the package may be worthwhile. For better performance, you may also want to check the [ncls](https://github.com/hunt-genes/ncls) package, although its documentation and methods seem to be limited.

I hope this helps.